# 'Attaching' Cropit with JQuery Filer

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-filer

I am really at a dead end guys. I am using Creative Dream JQuery Filer(now known as innostudio fileuploader) in a form data to upload images with a checkmark in them to flag the main image to use. I somehow need additional feature which is cropping, unfortunately JQuery Filer does not support cropping (correct me if I am wrong)

Below is my example where I can browse file and upload images and select a main image.
[image]

What I need from the cropping library are:

- Cropping before showing the preview in JQuery Filer
- Produce square/rectangle images (pre-set shape/size/ratio)

My question is, how can I use these 2 separate js library (if you have any other cropping library that works with JQuery filer, you may recommend me that one as long as the file uploader a free js library with checkmark capability) to come up with the desire output. Anyone can show me how or a link would be really good. Really appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Fileuploader (https://innostudio.de/fileuploader/) has a cropping option. According to the documentation what you need is `canvasImage` option.

This feature will crop the image only on Front-End, but if you need to crop the image on Back-End you will need something like https://github.com/eventviva/php-image-resize